# Is it possible to estimate a specific quantile of a prediction based on the results of ordinary linear regression?

Tags: regression, prediction, tolerance-interval

We can estimate mean value of a prediction with a specific confidence, we have an estimated value of a variance (MSE) and we also assume that prediction is a normally distributed random variable. Isn't it enough information to find any quantile of Y, given X=x (with the same confidence as the mean)?

Comment: Yes: this is called a *tolerance interval.*

Comment: Thank you! For some reason tolerance intervals are rarely mentioned in stats textbooks.